# how can i check django user groups in forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form defined from a model class. Depending from the user group of the logged in user, some fields should be remove if logged in user is not belong from certain group.i have a `producer` group, if logged in user is not belong form `producer` group then i want to remove the `time_pool` field from the forms. my code is showing this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` . how can i solve this issue?

my code is working i want to know is that a correct way if i initialized the user like this ?

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'time_pool',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        if not self.user.groups.filter(name__iexact='producer').exists():
            del self.fields['time_pool']
```

views.py

```
class NewsCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView, SuccessMessageMixin):
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = 'news/news_create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    success_message = "%(title)s was created successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(NewsCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

Comment: seems like you haven't initialized the form with `user`

Comment: ok how can i initialized it? would you like to explain it?

Comment: Pass "user" variable from view as a keyword argument, when creating the form object. E.g. in your view - `form = ArticleForm(user=request.user)`